# Преобразование Excel файла с помощью Pandas и xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Нужна помощь, пытаюсь автоматизировать составления технических заданий (хочу написать скрипт, который будет автоматически преобразовывать набор данных в Excel-файл определённого вида.

Итак, есть следующая выгрузка продукции в Excel-файле, которую необходимо закупить и поставить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуясь библиотекой Pandas, я смог структурировать данные и привести их в нужный мне вид:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time


def pivot(factories, budget):  # создаёт списки сводных таблиц для каждого грузополучателя, в соответствии с бюджетом
    df = []
    for factory in factories:
        temp_pivot = data_pt.query(f'Завод == ["{factory}"] & Раздел_ГКПЗ == ["{budget}"]')
        if temp_pivot.size != 0:
            df.append(temp_pivot)
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    budgets = ('РЕМОНТ', 'ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЯ', 'ИП_ТПИР')  # перечень статей бюджета
    factories = ('7Q11', '7Q31', '7Q41', '7Q91', '7Q61', '7QB1', '7QR1')  # коды грузополучателей
    data = pd.read_excel(r'D:/pyxcel/load_rele.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    data['Дата поставки'] = data['Дата поставки'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m')
    data.rename(columns={'Раздел ГКПЗ': 'Раздел_ГКПЗ'}, inplace=True)
    data['Завод'].replace(['7Q71', '7Q81', '7QA1'], '7Q61', inplace=True)
    data['Завод'].replace('7QC1', '7QB1', inplace=True)
    data['Раздел_ГКПЗ'].replace('ИП ТПИР', 'ИП_ТПИР', inplace=True)
    data_pt = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['Раздел_ГКПЗ', 'Завод', 'Номер лота', '№ материала', 'Краткий текст позиции',
                                          'ЕИ'], values=['Количество'], columns=['Дата поставки'],
                             aggfunc=np.sum).sort_values(by=['Краткий текст позиции'])
    tables_repairs = pivot(factories, budgets[0])
    tables_exploitation = pivot(factories, budgets[1])
    tables_investments = pivot(factories, budgets[2])
    data_pt.to_excel(r'D:/pyxcel/new_rele.xlsx')
    print('Lead time: {:.2f} secs.'.format(time.time() - start))
```

В итоге, я получаю 3 списка, тип элементов которых `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.
Для технического задания утверждена типовая форма, в которую мне нужно добавить данные, но как мне это сделать я не знаю.

Есть ли возможность вставить полученные датафреймы целиком в заранее заготовленный Excel-файл с помощью Pandas, либо описать создание формы технического задания с помощью модуля xlsxwriter и уже туда воткнуть эти сводные таблицы? Из технической документации по xlsxwriter я понял, что метод write() не работает с типом данных DataFrame.

Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки и помощь!